# Octave GUI development

Tags: user-interface, return, octave, workspace

I'm programming a GUI in Octave and was wondering how to implement code that the calls functions behind my buttons that will return a assigned value to the workspace.

To be more specific I have written down a code snippet which is dealing with my topic.

The original GUI can be found here: https://www.gomatlab.de/gui-in-octave-erstellen-t44037.html

What I'm trying to do is to modify the given code to my purpose (nothing from scratch).

```
function load_params(obj)
    clear h
    h = guidata(obj)
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.mat')
    result = load([pathname,filenname]) //Want to have result in my workspace
end;
//Create the button here 
h.load_params = uicontrol ('style', 'pushbutton' , 'units' , 'normalized' , 'string' , 'new parameters' , 'callback' , @load_parameters)
```

Comment: Ah, the code you've linked is based on my demo: https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/demo_uicontrol.m but with my name removed :-( but hey, what is your question?

Comment: Pressing the button simply triggers a callback function to run. Therefore your question as I understand it is really unrelated to GUI, and is basically "how do I cause a function to assign a value to a variable in the 'main' workspace?". Look at things like "global", "evalin", adding properties to the root figure object etc. Even better, make your button such that you also pass an object to the callback function as an argument, which is then modified appropriately inside the function.